# DateTimeFormat exception when trying to set ZonedDateTime

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson2

I am trying to set `ZonedDateTime` in request field as. -

```
.date(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of(ZONE_ID_EST)))
```

Request Model filed is -

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ZonedDateTimeSerializer.class)
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
ZonedDateTime date;
```

but I am getting `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-06-30T21:19:08.142000-04' could not be parsed at index 26`

I have tried below but same error

```
DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX");

  .......

ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of(ZONE_ID_EST));
    String formattedString = date.format(DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);

ZonedDateTime parsedDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(formattedString)
.........

.date(ZonedDateTime.parse(formattedString))
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: I think you need to set custom deserializer using [`@JsonDeserialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html).

Comment: It was working earlier but when I upgrade my Spring Boot Version from `1.5.x` to `2.3.1` it started giving this error. Not sure what I am missing